# Where are Public Folder permissions set with Exchange Server 2007?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook

When accessing a folder from the server...
Exchange Management Console > Public Folder Management Console > desired folder properties
...there is no permissions tab to be found.

I know this can be done via Outlook, but the real problem is somehow a public folder was created that Admin doesn't have rights to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the Exchange Management Shell

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310789.aspx

Comment: Another option could be to use third party tools like PowerGUI

Comment: Thanks guys.  Downloaded PowerGUI and installed the Exchange 2007 Power Pack.  From there it was cake!